# simplexml_load_file and 100mb+ XML file: Takes a lot of time to load and result in a Timeout

Tags: php, jquery, json, xml, rss

I've been using `simplexml_load_file` to parse a XML URL, however, the file size is above 100mb and instead of loading only the nodes, what's happening is that the script is loading the whole XML file before the nodes are extracted and parsed, what is resulting in a page `TimeOut`.

I'm using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Boutique</title>

 </head>
  <body>



<?php header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>



<!--   --><link rel="stylesheet" href="/va/artigos-complexos/afilio/afilio-vitrine.css" type="text/css" />
<div><p class="ofertasdotopovitrine">Conhe&ccedil;a nossas super ofertas!</p>
</div>
<div class="mainproductebayfloatright-bottom">

<?php

function parse($url, $offset = 1, $limit = -1)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $limitCriteria = '';
    if ($limit > 0) {
        $limitCriteria = 'and position() <= ' . ((int)$offset + (int)$limit + 1);
    }

    $products = array();
    $path = sprintf('//produto[position() >= %s %s]', (int)$offset, $limitCriteria);
    foreach($xml->xpath($path) as $product) {
        $products[] = array(
          'nome' => $product->nome,
          'preco_promocao' =>  $product->preco_promocao,
          'description' => $product->descricao,
          'link_imagem' =>  $product->link_imagem,
          'link_produto' =>  $product->link_produto,
          'preco_normal' =>  $product->preco_normal,
          'parcelas' =>  $product->parcelas,
          'vl_parcelas' =>  $product->vl_parcelas  
        );
    }
    return $products;
}
//XML GOES HERE
$products = parse('http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895987&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1010&format=XML', 5, 5);
?>


<?php
  foreach ($products as $product) {


  print '<div class="aroundebay"><div id="aroundebay2">';
    /* */
    print '<div class="titleebay"><a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="'. $product['link_produto'] . '">' . $product['nome'] . '"</a></div>';
    print '<div class="mainproduct"><a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="' . $product['link_produto'] . '"><img style="height:120px" src="' . $product['link_imagem'] . '"/><br/>';
    //print "De:;&nbspR$". $preco_normal . "<br/>";
    print '<span>Apenas&nbspR$' . $product['preco_promocao'] . '<br/></a></span></div>';
    //print "Em&nbsp" . $parcelas . "x de&nbsp:&nbspR$" . $vl_parcelas . "</a></span></div>";           
  print '</div></div>';
}


    ?>


</div>






 </body>
</html>
```

The CSS is irrelevant.

The script works just fine when you use a smaller XML, such as this one:

```
http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_get_boutique.php?boutiqueid=37930-895835&token=53e355b0a09ea0.74300807&progid=1681&format=XML
```

Would it be possible to load only the, for exemplo, 10 first nodes of the xml without having to load the whole file first?

I'm also accepting suggestions in other languages, such as `jQuery`.
Thanks in advance. You can also change the file format to JSON and RSS, just change `format=XML` to `format=JSON` or `format=RSS`.